# How to stop all running threads except the current thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

In my project I have provided an option for save multiple credentials. When a user logs in, they have to select their credential. In between if they want to move to another credential then they would have to logout and login to other credentials. Here I am not closing the application.

Now, in my project when someone click on Logout button then all Running Threads are getting stopped. Is there any shortcut method to stopped all running threads in my application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html

Comment: Maybe you could tell a bit more on what you're really trying to achieve. Can't really suggest anything else but System.exit() based on your current description..

Comment: I have update the question.please read it again

Comment: Automagically stopping all process threads except one, (which is what you seem to want),  is not supported on any OS I have ever seen.  I suggest you implement your logout/login mechanism using an alternative design that does not need this functionality.  Automagically stopping all process threads is, of course, very easy, as other posters have pointed out.

Comment: I still don't get this question.  When someone clicks Login all the threads stop?  And you _don't_ want this?  The last paragraph seems contradictory.

Comment: @Gray - yes. I put it through my 'Customer Requirement Spec' filter and it says that the OP wants a function to to terminate all threads except the caller.

Comment: I agree @Martin.  I think you're the closest to being correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them all in an ExecutorService and order it to shutdown all the threads in his pool.

Comment: This will interrupt (but not guarenteed to stop) all the threads in the services thread pool.  This is the best solution IMHO but might not be what the OP had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Simply have a stop condition in all your threads and set it when you want to stop them.

Answer (score 0):

`System.exit(n)` will stop all running user threads.

Comment: One problem is, Ronak, that you ask for 'method to stopped all running threads in my application' - that is effectively a process termination since there would be nothing left to execute your code.  I think you mean 'all other threads'.